# Slow insert on very large tables, (even in transactions)

Tags: optimization, insert, sqlite

I have a table with about 50 million rows, the table itself is fairly simple

```
CREATE TABLE Word (id integer PRIMARY KEY, word TEXT UNIQUE)
```

I then do an insert

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Word (word) VALUES (@word)
```

And get the Id of the value that was, (or was not), inserted.

```
SELECT id FROM Word WHERE word = @word
```

But the insert **and/or** the select, sometime take between 100ms and 1000ms

This is all done within a single transaction, where there are around ~1000 inserts.

So the 1000 inserts can take up to 10000ms (all *within a single transaction*).

Could the issue be because the table is large(ish)? While 50 million is not small, I wouldn't think it would be an issue?

How could I speed up my inserts?